# AMFPHP String size limit

Tags: string, actionscript-3, size, amfphp

Is there any limit (of about 65k) in amfphp sending strings?

I can not found any of that in the documentation and none to few people complaining about that.

But anything we send above 65k is getting cut (literaly) in the final part to 65k string when we recieved in the as3 client.

Thanks.

Comment: what version are you using? I have a vague recollection of fixing something in that direction in version 2.0, but I'm not sure. So if you're on an older version, you might want to try upgrading

Comment: Maybe kinda of noob questiong, but what is the propper way to know which amfphp version we are running?
we have checked most files and we can not find any number:
Thanks.

Comment: it's not obvious on the older versions, so it's not a noob question. If you send requests to a "gateway.php", it's 1.9 or older. If it's to Amfphp/ or Amfphp/index.php, it's 2.0 and older. There's a constant defined in Amfphp/ClassLoader.php, AMFPHP_VERSION, since 2.0  I think.

Comment: I just did a test, and at least with Amfphp 2.2 it works ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in fact was a restriction of older version.

Anyway this problem bring us the issue that we were sending big data over the net, we have optimize this besides updating version.

Thanks!